# Transfer to Udaipur airport

Tags: india, airport-transfer, rajasthan, udr

What are the available means of transport to get from Udaipur city center to [Udaipur's Maharana Pratap airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udaipur_Airport)? Please quote the prices as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikitravel's entry on Udaipur](http://wikitravel.org/en/Udaipur):

> Taxis to the city cost INR 500 and are the only means of transport to
>   and from the airport.

...and I'm not surprised to hear that. Until five years ago or so, public transport connectivity was bad with many major city airports too. You could potentially try taking a bus to the city outskirts but your bargaining power with taxis there will be even lower. Go to a crowded taxi stand, name a low price (like Rs100-200) and bargain hard. Walk away at the very first attempt of whatever the taxi drivers reply, one of them will eventually call you back.

EDIT by OP:

- Autorickshaw to airport is 250 rupees. First price quoted will be around 500.
- Local bus schedule, that is unbelievably hard to comprehend, will get you as far as Udaipur bypass but then you'll still have to catch a bus to Nimbahera, Chittorgarh or Dungla at the intersection. You can board the same buses at Udaipur bus stand with less hassle and the ride will set you back 50-80 rupees depending on the bus and a ticket examiner.

Comment: Added my own info to Ankur Banerjee's answer...