# Taxi from Udaipur airport to Karni fort, Bambora

Tags: india, airport-transfer, taxis, rajasthan, udr

I am looking for a transport for a group of ten from Udaipur airport to Karni fort, Bambora.

How can I make an advance booking?

Comment: See also: [Transfer to Udaipur airport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6137)

Answer (score 3):

Here are your options -

- Call & ask Karni Fort hotel to arrange for airport pickup. They would be happy to arrange the taxis for you.
- Check online if there are companies that advertise now, there have been some and there might some new ones.
- No advance booking. Land in Udaipur, take the airport taxis available.